# How do I report that Chrome's Remote Desktop causing multiple, severe problems?

Tags: sound, nautilus, google-chrome, gnome-terminal, remote-desktop

I'm new to Ubuntu...switching my homestation PC from Windows, over to Google Chromebook, and now onto your UBUNTU:GNOME...

I've always been able to control my homestation remotely using Chrome-RDP.  I've attempted this using your latest: 18.04 release, and it's caused massive instabilities in multiple functions.  Before going into more specific detail, I was wondering how / who to report these problems to?

Answer (score 0):

Visit the [support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523) of the developer, and provide a detailed explanation of how it misbehaves with 18.04, as well as the version of Chrome you are using. For that, click on the menu button, then click on Help, then About Google Chrome.

Please be prepared for requests to do things you may not think are relevant, as they know what's under the hood of their code and may be looking for things you won't see.